# Android Studio vs command line compile /w gradlew

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, continuous-integration, bamboo

As described [here in the Android Studio docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html), one can build an Android app from the command line with the gradle wrapper generated by Android Studio. The command line window in Android Studio shows exactly this, i.e. a call to gradlew assembleDebug (or a similar task). However starting a terminal on macOS and calling the gradle wrapper with that exact call sometimes yields other results, i.e. either [one is able to build from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762245/android-studio-build-works-gradle-command-line-fails), [or the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837922/build-fails-inside-android-studio-command-line-works), or both (which is ideal, but unfortunately not always true).

Who can explain what other settings the Android Studio IDE sets for their environment and where to find them, how to reproduce these settings easily in a CI environment (e.g. Jenkins, Bamboo, ...) and how one would consistently store these settings in a VCS along an Android project.

Comment: what does it mean that you have other results??

Comment: Other results being a failed build in either android studio or via command line.

Answer (score 1):

In the root of the project you have `gradlew.bat`, which is how you can run it in the first place. If you open this file, you see the code for building and everything else Gradle does.

Whether you build from the command line or ANdroid Studio, the `gradlew.bat` file is used. So building and other stuff you do with the `gradlew` command all use the same file whether it is from the command line or Android Studio's integrated tools.

You can open the file(s, there's `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` in the project root) and see how it works if you wanted too, though these files are usually automatically generated by Android Studio (it is possible to make your own config as well, though there's rarely a need for that). And for including in vcs, make sure the files aren't listed in .gitnore (or whatever vcs ignore extension you have)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but most of what you wrote is already in my question. Calling the gradle wrapper from command line is not the same as what android studio does. Most probably it is due to some environment variables being set by studio or something similar. I would like to find out what exactly it is to be  able to reproduce builds that are identical. Check out the linked questions on SO to read about others having these issues as well.

Comment: @Lennert there isn't a difference. It compiles Gradle into an Android application using `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat`. There isn't a difference, and if there is one it is in how it actually compiles it in terms of order. Build first then generate APK and then install it. You have left out something if you cna't get it to compile properly from the command line

Comment: When using the exact same command as Android Studio displays in its terminal window, the command line build does not work even though it does work in Android Studio. I don't want to go into details as to why it fails, as the actual error isn't what I am looking to solve. I am not the only one having these issues as can be witnessed from the links from my question, where quite a few people experience the same problem, i.e. inconsistency between command line and Android Studio builds using the exact same gradle command (and wrapper).

Comment: @Lennert - Have you found the difference? I see different behaviour from 2 different builds i.e. Android Studio build and command line build.

Comment: @RaviKanasagra Sorry for the late reply, I did not figure this out tbh. Just fixed my errors and went ahead. Would love to have the time to dig deeper but apparently there isn't a lot of resources to follow up on. Did you find a solution?